# ListPlot of a complicated function

Tags: plotting, discrete

I want to find the function $\Pi_i(s,\phi)$ as defined from the following identity:
$$
\Pi_i(s,\phi)=\frac{\phi^{s-1}c}{(s-1)!}\left[\frac{\text{d}^{s-2}}{\text{d}z^{s-2}}g_i(z)^s\right]_{z=1-\phi}\qquad i=1,2,
$$
where
$$
g_1(z)=x^{c-1}\quad\text{and}\quad g_2(z)=\frac{\gamma-2}{z}\frac{\Gamma(2-\gamma,k_{min}\ln(1/z))}{(k_{min}\ln(1/z))^{2-\gamma}}\,,
$$
where $c,\gamma,k_{min}$ are constants and $\Gamma(x,y)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.
To do so I wrote the following code for the case $i=1$, where I know that the result for the function $\Pi$ is the power law decay plotted together:

```
Clear[c, g1, P1,P2]
g1[x_, s_] := x^(s (c - 1));
P1[s_, \[Phi]_] = (\[Phi]^(s + 1) c)/(s + 1)! D[g1[z, s + 2], {z, s}] /. z :> 1 - \[Phi];
c = 3;
DiscretePlot[{P1[s - 2, 0.5], 0.3*s^(-(3/2))},{s,3,800},ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

The result is the following:
[image]

(the difference is not relevant since I am interested in the exponent of the power law). The problem is that I cannot get the same result for the more complicated function $g_2(x)$. I added these lines but even the definition of the function takes long time

```
\[Gamma] = 2.5;
kmin = 3;
g2[x_, s_] := ((\[Gamma] - 2)*(kmin*Log[1/x])^(\[Gamma] - 2)*Gamma[2-\[Gamma], kmin*Log[1/x]]/x )^s;
P2[s_, \[Phi]_] = (\[Phi]^(s + 1) c)/(s + 1)! D[g2[z, s + 2], {z, s}]/. z :> 1 - \[Phi];
```

I also tried something numerically but it not worth showing the code (it is one line with Table). Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the derivative in P2 for generic symbolic `s` is the time-consuming part. If you restrict the calculation of the derivative to when s has a numerical value, you can at least get some results.

It is still pretty slow when $s>40$, as one can imagine, but with patience you could probably get where you need to be.

````
γ = 2.5;
kmin = 3;
c = 3;

Clear[g2, P2]
g2[x_, s_] := ((γ - 2)*(kmin*Log[1/x])^(γ - 2)*
     Gamma[2 - γ, kmin*Log[1/x]]/x)^s;
P2[s_Integer, ϕ_] := 
 P2[s, ϕ] = (ϕ^(s + 1) c)/(s + 1)! D[g2[z, s + 2], {z, s}] /. 
   z :> 1 - ϕ

Table[{s, P2[s - 2, 0.5]}, {s, 3, 44}]

(* Out: 
{{3, 0.000377382}, {4, 0.0000727085}, {5, 0.0000151145}, 
 {6, 3.31137*10^-6}, {7, 7.53625*10^-7}, {8, 1.76512*10^-7}, {9, 4.22776*10^-8}, 
 {10, 1.03089*10^-8}, {11, 2.55071*10^-9}, {12, 6.38827*10^-10}, 
 {13, 1.61644*10^-10}, {14, 4.12612*10^-11}, {15, 1.06125*10^-11}, 
 {16, 2.74768*10^-12}, {17, 7.15557*10^-13}, 
 {18, 1.87313*10^-13}, {19, 4.926*10^-14}, {20, 1.30083*10^-14}, 
 {21, 3.44806*10^-15}, {22, 9.17072*10^-16}, {23, 2.44668*10^-16}, 
 {24, 6.54611*10^-17}, {25, 1.75598*10^-17}, {26, 4.72172*10^-18}, 
 {27, 1.27246*10^-18}, {28, 3.43624*10^-19}, {29, 9.29725*10^-20}, 
 {30, 2.52*10^-20}, {31, 6.84184*10^-21}, {32, 1.86048*10^-21}, 
 {33, 5.06659*10^-22}, {34, 1.38164*10^-22}, {35, 3.77275*10^-23}, 
 {36, 1.03131*10^-23}, {37, 2.82261*10^-24}, {38, 7.7419*10^-25}, 
 {39, 2.12231*10^-25}, {40, 5.81777*10^-26}, {41, 1.58707*10^-26}, 
 {42, 4.43454*10^-27}, {43, 1.23144*10^-27}, {44, 3.16982*10^-28}}
*)
```
````

Comment: Thanks! It works, I used ParallelTable but I don’t think it is possible to make a faster computation, is’t it? Thanks a lot anyway.